# I have 3 random numbers orders - how to find the probability of one of them being the largest?

Tags: probability, combinations

I have 3 random numbers (not integers) and all I know is the probabilities of:

1. number 1 to be larger than number 2 $= p_{12}$
2. number 1 to be larger than number 3 $= p_{13}$
3. number 2 to be larger than number 3 $= p_{23}$

How do I find the probability of number 1 being the largest of all three numbers?

Thanks

Comment: but proba of nbr 2 > nbr 1 = p_{21}$  = 1-p_{12}$. no?

Answer (score 2):

Unsufficient data.

Consider for example $(X_1,X_2,X_3)$ uniform on the set of triplets $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ such that $\{x_1,x_2,x_3\}=\{1,2,3\}$ (thus, there are $6$ possible outcomes) then every $p_{ij}$ is $\frac12$ and, by symmetry, $X_1$ is the largest with probability $\frac13$. But, if $(X_1,X_2,X_3)$ is uniform on the set of triplets $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ such that $\{x_1,x_2,x_3\}=\{1,2,3\}$ and $x_1\ne2$ (thus, there are $4$ possible outcomes) then  every $p_{ij}$ is $\frac12$ and $X_1$ is the largest with probability $\frac12$.

If each $X_i$ must be "not an integer (one wonders why?), replace $(1,2,3)$ by $(\mathrm e,\pi,\sqrt{42})$.

For absolutely continuous examples, consider $(X_1,X_2,X_3)$ uniform on the cube $K=[0,1]^3$ and $(X_1,X_2,X_3)$ uniform on the set $\{(x_1,x_2,x_3)\in K\mid(x_1-x_2)(x_1-x_3)\gt0\}$.